# Cache HTTP requests in browsers and AWS CDN, but not in intermediate proxies

Tags: caching, proxy, browser-cache, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS CDN for serving HTTP requests. My use case is, I want response to get cached in browser and on CDN, but not in intermediate proxies.

By setting :

```
Default TTL: 21600
```

in CDN distribution caching behavior, CDN caches it for 6 Hrs

and setting

```
Cache-Control: Private, max-age=21600
```

in origin, makes response cache-able in browser for 6 Hrs.

Now I have an additional scenario, where I want to cache files selectively in CDN and browser.
I tried setting `Minimum TTL : 0`, so cache control headers set by origin take effect on CDN. But as I don't want it get cached by intermediate proxies, I have to add private cache control, which makes it non cache-able in CDN.

Is there any way I can achieve this usecase? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `s-maxage` Cache-Control header?

In theory, you should be able to set this to specify the intermediary caching duration, whilst overriding it in CloudFront by setting the appropriate Minimum TTL (if this value is greater than the `s-maxage` value, CloudFront will use this value rather than the `s-maxage` value).

You can use the `maxage` value alongside `s-maxage` to set the end-client caching duration.